# The Graphics2D Fill Method in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d

I've just read that the ***fill*** method in Java paints one fewer pixel to the right and bottom.

For example, if you draw a `new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,10,20)`, then the drawing includes the pixels with `x = 10` and `y = 20`. If you fill the same rectangle, those pixels are not painted.

Why do those methods return different result although they work on the same object and do similar task? Is there any reason, or it's just a mistake?

Answer (score 3):

The [`Graphics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) API explains the difference between *drawing* the outline and *filling* the interior:

> Coordinates are infinitely thin and lie between the pixels of the output device. Operations that draw the outline of a figure operate by traversing an infinitely thin path between pixels with a pixel-sized pen that hangs down and to the right of the anchor point on the path. Operations that fill a figure operate by filling the interior of that infinitely thin path.

In particular,

> If you draw a figure that covers a given rectangle, that figure occupies one extra row of pixels on the right and bottom edges as compared to filling a figure that is bounded by that same rectangle.

Comment: [QuickDraw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickDraw#Graphics_primitives) used the same model, but it had a different API.